# Importing a mesh only work with active Inspector

Tags: angular, babylonjs

I have a strange problem in my angular app and I can't figure it out.
I am importing a mesh like this:

```
SceneLoader.ImportMesh("", "assets/models/", "model.gltf", this.scene, function(model) {});
```

But then I get this error:

```
Unable to load from assets/models/model.gltf: importMesh of unknown
```

Only when I start it with Inspector like this

```
Inspector.Show(this.scene, {});
```

the model is loaded correctly.

The model was exported from Blender in glTF Embedded format and it worked with Three.js also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got help in the [babylonjs forum.](https://forum.babylonjs.com/t/importing-a-mesh-only-works-with-active-inspector/44880/5?u=maxwell)

> add import "@babylonjs/loaders/glTF" to the import section and it will work.